# Converter for RJ45 port to SFP+

Tags: 10gbethernet, sfp

2 of my servers have an Intel X552 network adapter that has 2x 10GbE RJ45 ports. All my other equipment is at least dual RJ45/SFP+.

I'm looking at upgrading my core network to 10GbE and I'd like to use fibre cabling exclusively if possible.

Is there anything that will allow me to convert an RJ45 port to SFP+? I've found media converters like [these](https://www.fs.com/au/c/ethernet-media-converters-1037) but I was hoping for something more like a transceiver that plugs straight into the port.

Comment: If your switch only has SFP ports then you can use a RJ45 SFP module in your switch. If it has both RJ45 and SFP then why bother converting? 10GbE is 10GbE.
If you want all your servers to hook up to the network the same way then replace the network card as Chopper3 suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The regular 'copper'/RJ-45 connector pin-outs cannot provide the power needed to drive the optics to allow you to do what you want to - you'll have to use a media converter or just swap out the NIC make/model.

Comment: Out of interest, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet indicates that 100W PoE for 10GBASE-T is possible. Presumably that would enable a transceiver?

Comment: Yes but PoE is driven by the switch not the NIC.

Comment: Ah yes, of course.